# Using fadeout, fadein in JQuery with img

Tags: jquery

Im new to jQuery, and what im trying to accomplish is I want a image to fade in and out, and after its finished fading out, I want to change the image the image while fading in the new src. is not exactly working the way I want it to. Here is what I have so far. Any help would be very helpful.

```
<img src="images/airport1.jpg" Height="200" Width="500" id="main_pic"/> 
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        changePicture();
    });
});
function changePicture() {
    $("#main_pic").fadeOut(5000).delay(3500).attr('src', "images/airport2.jpg").fadeIn(5000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You say its not working the way you want. What's happening and how is that different than what you expect?

Comment: Ask a specific question, noone is going to do your work for you.

Comment: Changing the source has the drawback in that it will need to do an HTTP request to load the image if you haven't preloaded the image already.  I think I know where you're going with this post, but don't be frustrated if you can't get it to work perfectly.

Comment: What is doing is when the second image appear, it doesnt fade in, it just show up and then fades out the way I expect it to

Comment: Thanks, kevin...ya I saw this done on a website that I was browsing and I thought it was pretty cool and wanted to try and duplicate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.delay`, I suggest loading the new image and doing `fadeIn` inside the callback.

```
function changePicture() {
    $("#main_pic").fadeOut(5000, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', "images/airport2.jpg").fadeIn(5000);
    });
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/v5fqB/